# Weird Corruption Issue

Tags: windows, usb

Windows 7 Professional
750GB Hard drive, no corruption, chkdsk shows now errors.

I installed a new internal 1TB hard drive in the laptop.  Plugged in the 750GB drive via USB enclusure.

I copy over files (a folder of jpgs for instance).

If I view them on the USB enclosure, or if I view the copied files, they are corrupted.  Chkdsk on the good usb drive shows tons of corruption.  But if I put the 750GB drive back in and bot, everything looks OK.

What could the problem possibly be?  At a total loss here.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it looks like a problem with the USB enclosure. I could be that you're not supplying enough power to it, and so it's showing read errors on the disk. Alternatively, the enclosure itself might be not working correctly. If the enclosure has two USB plugs, plug both in and retry, as that will supply more power to the enclosure and therefore to the disk.